# surge.sh | Create subdomain of custom domain using surge.sh plus

Tags: subdomain, surge.sh

I'm a surge.sh plus customer, with a custom domain, let's say

`http://bobswidgets.com`

However, Bob has asked me to set up a subdomain for his new bespoke service. He wants `custom.bobswidgets.com`

But I can't figure out how to do this... and whether it's part of the surge plus package I have, or if I need to set this up separately.

Answer (score 5):

I understand from the team at surge.sh that there are many ways to do this, but here's how I did it.

I'm assuming you already (as I did) have a site, with a custom domain, setup & running on surge.sh

First, you need to add a CNAME record to your DNS entry. In my case it's `custom.bobswidgets.com` and it should point to surge's domain `na-west1.surge.sh`

Now you can deploy the content for your subdomain directly with surge using `surge /path/to/project -d http://custom.bobswidgets.com`

Or you can include a `CNAME` file at the root of your content director, with the contents (It doesn't have an extension or anything)

`custom.bobswidgets.com`

Then use `surge /path/to/project` from your terminal

Essentially, it's exactly the same as the instructions for a normal custom domain - as https://surge.sh/help/adding-a-custom-domain - but using the details for your subdomain.

Comment: Is that possible to setup wildcard domain with surge like
surge path/to/my-project *.my-custom-domain.com